# Perforce Integrate command to remove local files/directories which are not present in repository

Tags: perforce

I am looking for a perforce integrate/get-latest command which would fetch the latest/updated-code and remove the files/folders that have been moved/deleted from the perforce(server) repository.

Is there any way by which I can get a clean copy of the perforce repository, without creating a new workspace/local directory?

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [sync](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/sync.html) command. It will grab the latest files, and it will remove any files that were deleted. I'm pretty sure it won't remove the directories, though, at least not on Windows.

To get a clean copy, you can delete the local files, and sync using the '-f' flag.

Comment: In addition to this, there is a script/batch file I have somewhere that creates a list orphaned (e.g. obj etc) files (using `p4 diff2`) and prompts the user to delete them. It is really useful and quick way to restore a workspace to the clean/server state. ... I will dig it out tomorrow and post it.

Answer (score 3):

As of release 2014.1, you can get a clean copy of the repository by using "p4 sync" and "p4 clean".  The "p4 sync" command will fetch the latest versions of files from the repository; the "p4 clean" command will remove/refresh anything in your workspace that was not put there by a sync:

http://www.perforce.com/blog/140501/p4-clean-make-workspace-shine

Setting the "rmdir" option in your client spec will tell "sync" and "clean" to remove empty directories as they are emptied by those commands:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_client.html#d0e7978